# Napari doesn't display full resolution

Tags: python, python-napari

I want to visualize a large tiff (65Kx35K) files using `Napari 4.18` but Napari does not display the image at full resolution. Instead at best it display a lower and pixelized image.

See the attached image where I compare the display between Napari (left) and ImageJ (right). We can see that resolution is different.

[image: Resolution comparison]

Is there are option to display images at full resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the image was not in a pyramid form at first and Napari does not say anything about it. As a consequence I have to provide a list: the original image plus enough lower resolution images until the smaller image dimension is smaller than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE which in my case is 16384.

So the code would become:

```
from skimage import io
import napari
img = io.imread('myimage.tif')
viewer = napari.Viewer()
viewer.add_image([img, img[::2,::2], img[::4,::4]])
```

The complete answer can be found [here](https://forum.image.sc/t/napari-does-not-display-full-resolution/86982).